# Extending Aerial Range of 360 USB receiver

Tags: wireless

I have modded an Xbox 360 usb wireless receiver so that it sits inside my PC, but the problem I have appears to be range as it regularly drops the connection to controlers. The connection from the motherboard to the device is solid so it could be the computer case blocking the signal or would the RFI from the computer and its power supply be corrupting the data?

For reference, here is what the wireless receiver board looks like:

[image]

It seems like the gold band around the edge is the aerial. I have tried soldering a cable to this and running it into the front fascia of my PC case (which is plastic), but that seemed to make little difference. I have read that it is possible to extend such an aerial, but I know very little about electronics so I am   not sure what's involved. Am I  using the wrong type of cable ? Is there anything else I am doing wrong?

Any insight onto how to improve the signal by effectively moving the aerial would be great!

Answer (score 1):

1: As brhans said, that gold rim-trace looks like it's supposed to be connected to a (now removed) metal (or foil tape) RFI/EMI shield to protect the "soft parts" of the board from harmful interferance. That needs to be replaced.

2: Also as brhans said, your antenna is the gold trace at the far right of the board.

3: If you want to attach an external antenna to this device, you can solder on an [antenna connector](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9144?gclid=CjwKEAiA27G1BRCEopST9M39gykSJADQyqAlDcgG0lzxjcdaGBxrl0paAJmxk_LNBJFgaNNynH0lMxoCFTHw_wcB) to attach the coax feedline to like so:

"Scratch off" the existing antenna (only the gold part).
 *(**DANGEROUS** if you don't have any pcb modifying experience)*

Attach antenna connector to board near antenna signal trace (red circle in image below)

Solder jumpers from connector's signal pin/pad to antenna signal trace (red circle in image), and from connector's ground &/or shield pin(s)/pad(s) to your ground plane (blue dot in image)

Buy/make an antenna for your board's rf frequency (and impedance), attach its cable to your new antenna connector, then mount the new antenna somewhere as far away from metal surfaces as possible (and obviously *outside* of the metal pc case).

[image: decorated board]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It sounds complicated! I was following a guide here: http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/how-to-m11x-internal-xbox-360-wireless-gaming-receiver.711810/ The images have gone unfortunately, but they cut the antenna off then just soldered a wire to something.... It can't be that simple though right?

Comment: FYI I only read that page down to the "Hot Air Rework Station highly recommended" in the "needed supplies" and the first step of "dismantle (i.e. remove every single component from) the pcb." I personally design/build/rework & solder pcbs with SMD devices using my Hakko thermo-controlled soldering station with mutiple precision tips, custom liquid fluxes, etc. but I myself WOULD NOT ATTEMPT that first step, and DO NOT OWN a hot air rework station! He's telling you to basically start over & re-manufacture the entire thing "from scratch."

Comment: But, as a more direct answer to your "It can't be that simple though, right?" query: If you're willing to redesign/remanufacture the whole device without the benefit of having electronics factory tools, then it's about as easy as that sounds. As for "just soldering something on," Yes, you _could_ directly solder on a piece of coax wire for your new antenna, rather than soldering on the connector like I linked. However, that only saves the one step of gluing the connector to the pcb, and coax is harder to solder (not to mention the maintenance advantage of plug/unplug vs solder/desolder).

Answer (score 0):

The large metal box which is your PC case is almost certainly shielding that module's RF communication from the outside.
The gold track on the right is the antenna.
The gold around the other edges is for grounding (was there a metal cover over most of the board touching those edges?).
Extending or otherwise modifying that antenna is not for the faint of heart or anyone else who doesn't know how RF works on PCBs.
Your best option would be to locate that board somewhere inside your PC case such that the antenna is in an open space without any metal blocking its 'view' of the outside - maybe in an open drive bay.
Also don't mount it flat onto any metal (at least not the antenna part). Try to keep the antenna as far from any metal as you can.
If you're really daring there is a mod you can make to be able to attach an external antenna to that board, but you'd need to be confident with desoldering & resoldering some of those tiny surface-mount components...